# R Shiny: download multiple local images in zip file

Tags: r, image, shiny, download, zip

Simply put, I'd like my app to allow the user to filter images with certain characteristics and consequently allow them to download the selected images into a zip file. The images are stored locally.

I've been able to add the images as thumbnails and allow the user to download the data associated with it (as a .csv) but not the actual images.

Here's what I have:

```
df <- read.csv("./imagedata.csv")

thumbnails <- list.files(path = "./localstore/", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
                         full.names = F, recursive = FALSE,
                         ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)


thumbnail_path = "./localstore/"


#----------------------------------Process Thumbnnail----------------------------------#

steps <- 0
out <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))

for (i in df$Thumbnail) {
  
  out[i] <- knitr::image_uri(i)
  
  steps <- steps + 1
  
}
print(steps)


ProcessedIcon <- as.data.frame(unlist(out))


Icon <-  paste("<img src=", ProcessedIcon$`unlist(out)` ,"></img>", sep = "")

df_Icon <- cbind(df, Icon)



#--------------------------------------- UI ---------------------------------------#

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = span(img(src = "logo.png", height = 35), img(src = "logo2.png", height = 35))),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      
      menuItem("Item Category", tabName = "category", icon = icon("file"),
               
               selectInput(inputId = "ItemCategory",
                           label = "", 
                           choices = unique(df$ItemCategory),
                           selected = unique(df$ItemCategory), 
                           multiple = TRUE,
                           selectize = TRUE, 
                           width = NULL, 
                           size = NULL)
),
      menuItem("Item Sub-category", tabName = "subcategory", icon = icon("copy"),
               selectInput(inputId = "ItemSubCategory",
                           label = "", 
                           choices = unique(df$SubCategory),
                           selected = unique(df$SubCategory), 
                           multiple = TRUE,
                           selectize = TRUE, 
                           width = NULL, 
                           size = NULL)
               
      ),
      
      br(),
      
      br(),
      column(11, align = "center",
             downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data"), class = "butt"),
      tags$head(tags$style(".butt{font:black;}")),
      
      br(),
      
      br(),
      column(11, align = "center",
             downloadButton("downloadImages", "Download Images"), class = "butt"),
      tags$head(tags$style(".butt{font:black;}"))
      
    )
  ),
  
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    DT::dataTableOutput('dftable'),
    
  )
)

#--------------------------------------- Server ---------------------------------------#

server <- function(input, output) {




#------------------------------------Download table-------------------------------#  
  
  Info_Database <-  reactive  ({
    
    df %>%
      filter(ItemCategory %in% c(input$ItemCategory)) %>% 
      filter(SubCategory %in% c(input$ItemSubCategory)) %>%
      select(-Thumbnail)
    
  })


#------------------------------------Display table-------------------------------#  
  
  table <-  reactive  ({
    
    df_Icon %>%
      select(Icon, ItemCategory, SubCategory, QualityOfImage, Recognisability)%>% 
      filter(ItemCategory %in% c(input$ItemCategory)) %>%
      filter(SubCategory %in% c(input$ItemSubCategory)) %>%
    
  })
  
  
  
  output$dftable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    
    DT::datatable(table(), escape = FALSE, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
    
    
  })
  
  # download handler- Database
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('ImageDatabase_', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      write.csv(Info_Database(), con)
    }
  )
  

# here's where I'm totally lost
  # download handler- Images
  #output$downloadImages <- downloadHandler(
    
  #) 
  
  
}
```

imagedata.csv should look like:

| ItemCategory | SubCategory | QualityOfImage | Recognisability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Animal | Cat | 5 | 4 |
| Animal | Dog | 4 | 3 |
| Food | Banana | 3 | 4 |
| Objects | House | 5 | 5 |

Display table should look like:

| Icon | ItemCategory | SubCategory | QualityOfImage | Recognisability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Text] | Animal | Cat | 5 | 4 |
| [image: Text] | Animal | Dog | 4 | 3 |
| [image: Text] | Food | Banana | 3 | 4 |
| [image: Text] | Objects | House | 5 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

### First things first

A [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would tremendously increase your chances of getting an answer, because nobody wants first to re-create your data structure first to be able to help you.

### Aproach

I would follow a slightly different approach. Rather than encoding the pictures, I would use an `<img>` tag to include them.

### Setup

*N.B.* All My SO answers are sitting in *Project Root* - this is not important for this solution, but necessary to re-run the example. Pics are taken from your example.

```
Project Root
|- .Rproj
|- Download
   |- app.R
   |- www
      |- pic-1.jpg
      |- pic-2.png
      |- pic-3.png
      |- pic-4.jpg
```

#### `app.R`

```r
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(here)
library(purrr)

all_pics <- list.files(here("Download", "www"), pattern = "\\.jpg$|\\.png$")

my_data <- tibble(Icon = all_pics, 
                  ItemCategory = c("Animal", "Objects", "Objects", "Animal"), 
                  SubCategory = c("Cat", "Banana", "House", "Dog"))

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Download Pics and Table"),
   sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("category", "Category:", 
                  c("All", my_data %>% pull(ItemCategory)),
                  "All"),
      downloadButton("dwnld_data", "Download Data"),
      downloadButton("dwnld_pics", "Download Pictures")
   ),
   mainPanel(
      DTOutput("tbl")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
   get_data <- reactive({
      my_data %>%
         filter(input$category == "All" |
                   ItemCategory == input$category) %>% 
         mutate(IconPath = map_chr(Icon, ~ as.character(img(src = .x, 
                                                            height = "50px", 
                                                            width = "50px"))))
   })
   
   output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(
         get_data() %>% 
            select(Icon = IconPath, Category = ItemCategory, 
                   "Sub Category" = SubCategory),
         escape = FALSE
      )
   })
   
   output$dwnld_data <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
         paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
      },
      content = function(file) {
         write.csv(get_data() %>% 
                      select(Icon, Category = ItemCategory, 
                             "Sub Category" = SubCategory), file,
                   row.names = FALSE)
      }
   )
   
   output$dwnld_pics <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
         paste0("pics-", Sys.Date(), ".zip")
      },
      content = function(file) {
         fns <- get_data() %>% 
            pull(Icon)
         zip(file,
             file.path(here("Download", "www"), fns), 
             flags = "-r9Xj")
      }
   )
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Explanation

1. All pics are in the `www` folder, from where `shiny` can add them to the page via the `<img>` tag.
2. In my `my_data` reactive, I filter the data according to the selections and add a string representation of the `<img>` tag, where I set height and width for the thumbnail sized pictures.
3. In `renderDatatable` I use `escape = FALSE` to **not** escape the HTML code and to render the picture.
4. Then the `downloadHandler` is rather straight forward, loop through all selected files and add them to a zip.

*N.B.* Theoretically you could also stay with your URI encoding strategy if you must. Your `downloadHandler` would become a bit more complicated in this case then however. You would first need to decode the encoded image string, store it to a temporary file and add this temporary file to the zip. Unless there are good reasons to go for this approach, I would not add this layer of complication.